Why does quantum circuit need to be run even though the probability is already in the formula?
In classical computing, it's clear by intuition why we need to run a program code to check whether a large odd integer number is prime or not.
It can be computed manually for such large number, but of course it's exhausting.
With the same analogy, why we need to run the quantum circuit when the circuit is already tell us, composed by unitary matrix operations, density matrices, and the exact probabilities are already there in the formula without requiring to actually shot the experiment?
Is it related with purity of state?

In some sense you are correct - a circuit is composed of an initial vector that is then acted upon by one or more unitary matrices, and the final probabilities are computable by just using a regular computer and multiplying the initial vector by all these unitary matrices. But you will quickly find that circuits with more than ~40 qubits lead to very big matrices, that will take a long time to compute on a regular computer. In fact that time grows exponentially with the number of qubits (barring any algorithmic tricks that one can play for specific circuits).
The alternative is to now run the circuit on a quantum computer, where there is an initial quantum state vector, and the unitary matrices are performed physically with quantum operations, which will lead you to a final quantum state vector. This is a much more efficient method to execute the circuit, however we cannnot inspect the individual amplitudes of all the basis states in this quantum state (regardless of pure or mixed) because quantum mechanics dictates that when we observe a quantum state, it will collapse and pick one basis state to show. So really that's all we can do:  measure it (with a 'shot') causing the state to collapse and record the results. This is why we have to do it many times over to get the probabilities.

It's like saying classical full adder circuit output has been defined based on combination of logical operation like AND, OR, XOR, NOT. Its complexity logical operation grow as the bit increase.
Same like quantum circuit, except the matrix operations grow as the qubit increase beside of logical operations.
Both classical circuit and quantum circuit can be emulated on classical software program.
